# Query SQL Database from Svelte App Backend

Tags: sql, node.js, database, backend, svelte

I am a beginner in Svelte, so maybe my understanding of the Tech Stack of a Svelte app is incorrect yet.

I have a SQL DB and I would like to reach it from the backend of my Svelte app. For the moment I am using the default template `npx degit sveltejs/template my-svelte-project`. I think the backend is a nodejs server, is it correct?

How can I query my DB from here and have an API for the front?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there is no backend at all when you do `npx degit sveltejs/template my-svelte-project`. You only get the environment that you need to develop your frontend.
You might want to look at [SvelteKit](https://kit.svelte.dev/) for a combination of a Svelte frontend and backend capabilities.